# How do I resolve a cors error on a fetch or 401?

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch

So I've been experiencing this CORS error and a 401 and have tried chrome plugins to allow for cors with no luck. Here are the errors I'm getting after disabling cors via the plugin:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://api.playground.klarna.com/payments/v1/sessions' from origin 'https://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

Error: TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

Before enabling the CORS Chrome Extension I was receiving a Allow-Access-Control-Origin is not set on the first error message. Along with this in the network tab I'm getting a 401 Preflight which indicates unauthorized but I'm setting the Authorization header with the correct credentials so not sure what's happening here. I'm using the codeigniter php framework.

I'm using Basic auth with:

```
var auth = 'Basic ' + btoa(username:password);
```

Here's the code:

```
   let postDataSession = {
                    "purchase_country" : bookingData.purchase_country, 
                    "purchase_currency" : bookingData.purchase_currency,
                    "locale" : bookingData.locale,
                    "order_amount" : bookingData.order_amount,
                    "order_tax_amount" : 0,
                    "order_lines" : [{
                        //"type" : "physical",
                        "reference" : bookingData.order_lines.reference,
                        "name" : bookingData.item_name,
                        "quantity" : 1,
                        "unit_price" : bookingData.order_amount,
                        "tax_rate" : 0,
                        "total_amount" : bookingData.order_amount,
                        "total_discount_amount": 0,
                        "total_tax_amount" : 0
                    }]
                };
```

```
                    fetch('https://api.playground.klarna.com/payments/v1/sessions', {
                                method: 'POST',
                                //mode: 'no-cors',
                                //Authorization: auth,
                                headers: {
                                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                                    'Authorization':  auth,
                                    //'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' : true,
                                    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' : 'pm-u, pm-h0, pm-h1, pm-h3, pm-o0, pm-o1, pm-o2, pm-o3, authorization',   
                                    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST',    
                                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'https://localhost',
                                    'ACCESS-CONTROL-MAX-AGE' : 3600,
                                    'referrer-policy': 'no-referrer-when-downgrade'
                                },
                                body: JSON.stringify(postDataSession),
                                
                            })
                            .then(function(response) {
                             //The following method initializes the Klarna Payments JS library
                            //window.location.href = baseurl + "customer/klarna_checkout_page";

                            if (!response.ok) {
                                return response.text().then(result => Promise.reject(new Error(result)));
                                console.log(response.status);
                             }
                                console.log(response.json(), response);
                                return response.json();
                            })
 
                           // .then(function(session) {
                           //     window.location.href = baseurl + "customer/klarna_checkout_page";
                           // })
                            .then(function(result) {
                                // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
                                // error, you should display the localized error message to your
                                // customer using `error.message`.
                                if (result.error) {
                                    alert(result.error.message);
                                }
                                console.log(result);

                            })
                            .catch(function(error) {
                                console.error('Error:', error);
                            });
```

I've tried it the mode set to no-cors and receive the same response. I've used postman to post the request with the same data and in postman a response is received. Not sure if I'm either missing or overlooking something so a fresh perspective would be helpful. Does anyone have any idea how to proceed with resolving this issue? I want to avoid having to deploy this code to the live domain and be able to test the response on localhost, not sure if that's at all possible with cors.

Comment: How exactly are you composing `auth`?

Comment: @ChrisG var auth = 'Basic ' + btoa(username:password);

Comment: Is that the exact code you're using...?

Comment: I am also facing the same problem, the error of either 401 or CROS policy with Allow-Access-Control-Origin.

Comment: Based on [this](https://developers.klarna.com/documentation/klarna-payments/integration-guide/) my guess is that Klarna doesn't support API access from browser-side JavaScript. Which makes sense, given that you'd expose credentials to the website visitor that way.

Comment: Preflight is not about credentials really. It's an OPTIONS request that determines what HTTP methods can be used upon the API.

Comment: @ChrisG  Yes. That was on my mind but just wanted to get an outside opinion to see if something was off. Such a pain but I guess it looks like I may have to run the test and develop on live to overcome this, that would theoretically work right?. & Leo Right but the 401 is usually for unauthorized access so I thought they may be related. Thanks

Comment: If by "develop on live" you mean you'll still make API requests from in-browser JS, then I don't think that'll work. The API is not meant to be used from inside a browser, and thus the server doesn't send header that allow CORS. The browser detects this and blocks the request. You need to make API requests from your backend.

Comment: @ChrisG Huh? Does that even include using fetch to make the request? I have a PHP backend and there doesn't appear to be any documentation for Klarna to integrate that. I would have expected using fetch to make the request to create the session would work based on this Integration guide: https://developers.klarna.com/documentation/klarna-payments/single-call-descriptions/create-session/

Comment: Literally the first sentence of that guide is "A Klarna Payments session is created *server-side* via our REST API." And why would there be documentation on how to use PHP to make API requests? Anybody who uses a) PHP b) an API is supposed to know how to do that or know how to find out how to do that. It's not Klarna's job to teach you a basic mechanism of PHP web development. Klarna's API is documented just fine, i.e. it lists the endpoints and what data they expect / reply with. Here's a library you can use: https://requests.ryanmccue.info/

Comment: @ChrisG Aah I see, that makes perfect sense. So fetch is only good for client side requests so wouldn't work in this instance. Awesome I'll take the php route then, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Browser extensions are notoriously useless at dealing with preflighted requests. It won't help here.
- No-cors mode makes the browser *silently fail* anything that requires CORS permission instead of throwing an exception. It won't help here.
- Postman isn't a browser. It's requests aren't triggered by visiting a website. It doesn't implement the Same Origin Policy and doesn't need permission from CORS.

> I'm getting a 401 Preflight which indicates unauthorized but I'm setting the Authorization header with the correct credentials so not sure what's happening here.

The browser is making a preflight request asking permission to send a POST request with credentials.

The server is getting the preflight request and complaining that it doesn't have credentials on it.

Either:

- Change the server you are making the request to so it grants you permission in your development environment. It needs to allow OPTIONS requests without credentials on them.
- Use a proxy that relays your requests to the server

Answer (score 2):

Is your backend .net core web services?   If so, I have seen this problem when you call UseCors after UseAuthentication in your pipeline.   If you do that, you will need an authenticated token to do the preflight which is why you get a cors error throwing the exception.   Move UseCors to before UseAuthentication so that a CORS response does not have to go through the Authentication middleware first.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).